# Grant access to an S3 bucket for a specific user only, no public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to configure an S3 bucket so it's only accessible for a specific user, not the public.

I've created a user called s3-injury-log and the following bucket policy

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1542998309644",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "Stmt1542998308012",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::injury-log",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::058842494618:user/s3-injury-log"]
        }
    }]
}
```

MY "Block all public access" tab is as the following

```
Block all public access - Off
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs) - On
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs) - On
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket policies - Off
Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket policies - Off
```

But when trying to put an object into the bucket (using aws java libs) I get the following error message

```
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: CC71A7EFAFC9BBDB; S3 Extended Request ID: klrwopIIJK3PsJzEw
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your policy is not correct, which only allows bucket-level actions. Therefore PutObject action is denied, which is object-level.

Just update your policy to allow object-level actions too:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1542998309644",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "Stmt1542998308012",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::injury-log",
            "arn:aws:s3:::injury-log/*"
        ]
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::058842494618:user/s3-injury-log"]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: This policy should work. Just make sure that you are using the right credentials, e.g. try uploading a file using AWS CLI.